# Return 0 as data for months with no data

Tags: laravel, eloquent, chart.js

Im using Chart.js to show the total number of transactions (count) for each month.

```
$dataTotal = ModelName::select(DB::raw('count(id) as count'), DB::raw("MONTH(created_at)  as month")) 
                        ->where('org_id', auth()->user()->org_id)
                        ->where('result_code', 200)
                        ->groupBy('month')
                        ->orderBy('month')
                        ->get()
                        ->toArray();
```

The query itself is fine, except for the problem that if there is no records in a month then it doesn't return `0` for that month. Which results in the graph not rendering properly.

Does anyone have any suggestions, on how i can implement it so that i receive full resultsets?

The desired format is:

```
array (
0 => 
array (
  'count' => 0,
  'month' => 1,
),
1 => 
array (
  'count' => 5,
  'month' => 2,
),
2 => 
array (
  'count' => 0,
  'month' => 3,
),
3 => 
array (
  'count' => 4,
  'month' => 4,
),
4 => 
array (
  'count' => 0,
  'month' => 5,
),
5 => 
array (
  'count' => 4,
  'month' => 6,
),
6 => 
array (
  'count' => 51225,
  'month' => 7,
),
7 => 
array (
  'count' => 4,
  'month' => 8,
),
8 => 
array (
  'count' => 0,
  'month' => 9,
),
9 => 
array (
  'count' => 0,
  'month' => 10,
),
10 => 
array (
  'count' => 0,
  'month' => 11,
),
11 => 
array (
  'count' => 0,
  'month' => 12,
),
```

)

Comment: My suggestion would be to return the data, and use any frontend logic to iterate over every month of the year, and if no array index is found, you could return 0.

Comment: what does it return instead of 0 then?

Comment: Nothing... Only returns months with data. My intention is to return 0 for months with no data

Answer (score 0):

Below (pseudo) code uses the power off the Laravel collection.
I suggest you read through the docs of Laravel on collections: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-first-where

```php
// Your original query slightly altered (pay attention to the toArray being removed)
// $models = ModelName::select(
//   DB::raw('count(id) as count'), 
//   DB::raw("MONTH(created_at)  as month")
// ) 
//     ->where('org_id', auth()->user()->org_id)
//     ->where('result_code', 200)
//     ->groupBy('month')
//     ->orderBy('month')
//     ->get();

// $models is now resembles your result from the above.
$models = collect([
  ['count' => 1, 'month' => 1],
  ['count' => 10, 'month' => 3],
  ['count' => 1, 'month' => 5],
  ['count' => 15, 'month' => 7],
  ['count' => 1, 'month' => 9],
  ['count' => 25, 'month' => 11],
]);

$months = collect(range(1, 12))->map(
  function ($month) use ($models) {
    $match = $models->firstWhere('month', $month);
    return $match ? $match['count'] : 0;
  }
);
```

Result of $months

```
=> Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1046
     all: [
       1,
       0,
       10,
       0,
       1,
       0,
       15,
       0,
       1,
       0,
       25,
       0,
     ],
   }
```

Comment: The desired result is in the form of array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'count' => 4,
    'month' => 5,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'count' => 51225,
    'month' => 6,
  ),
)

Comment: I have updated the question with the desired outcome

Answer (score 0):

Though it is not tested personally by me but as per documentation. In your model you can do [attribute casting](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting).

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ModelName extends Model
{
    
    protected $casts = [
        'count' => 'integer',
    ];
}
```

So now, count attribute will always be cast to a integer when you access it, even if the underlying value is stored in the database as null.
Also we know that if we typecast null value to integer it will return 0.
eg `$n = null; echo (int)$n; // answer is 0` 
Note: It might be correct, so if it didn't work please tell in the comments.